# Simplify exception catching in controllers

Tags: spring-mvc, controller, try-catch

I'm making a Web Service using Spring MVC. Controllers are called directly by the user (through despatcher servlet) and response are returned as JSON. I think that the use of controllers via annotation is very handy, but I find quite boring catching exception in each controller. The exceptions are always the same, and also the response for each exception is the same, so can I define how to catch them just one time instead of in each controller?
I was thinking about something like a filter, but maybe this is not a good idea... Any hint?

Now my controllers looks like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/do")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')") 
public class UselessController {

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@PreAuthorize("#bar == principal.bar")
public ResponseEntity foo(@RequestParam int bar) {

    try {
        //do something
    } catch (SomeTypeOfException stExc) {
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    } catch (NoResultException nrExc) {
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.PRECONDITION_FAILED);
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.METHOD_FAILURE);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is a [HandlerExceptionResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerExceptionResolver.html). If all you need is just a simple resolver for most common exceptions, implement the interface (there are also some ready-made implementations, see 'All Known Implementing Classes' in the doc) and annotate it as a component so it's picked up at start up time (at least I don't recall ever needing to "register" it separately or anything like that). If you need more fine-grained control, you can do so with code in your own HandlerExceptionResolver, or create a [SimpleMappingExceptionResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/SimpleMappingExceptionResolver.html) to map different exceptions to their own error views, which is usually done through the xml-configs.